# Snowflake DATEDIFF vs Hive

Tags: hive, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Im trying to rewrite hive query into Snowflake
Not sure that got this part correctly
Hive query:

```
AND (    
    ((unix_timestamp()-unix_timestamp(fs.Created_Date,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))/86400>=8 and st.mtcn is null)

OR  ((unix_timestamp(st.Created_Date,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')-unix_timestamp(fs.Created_Date,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))/86400>=8)   

OR ((unix_timestamp(st.Created_Date,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')-unix_timestamp(mt.opacket_transactiontime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))/86400>=8)

)

AND (spc.spacket_disposition='A')     
AND unix_timestamp(mt.OPacket_TransactionTime) >= unix_timestamp('2021-07-11 00:00:00')
```

In snowflake I have tried this:

```
AND (    
    (DATEDIFF(day,current_Date,TO_DATE(fs.Created_Date))>=8 and st.mtcn is null)

OR  (DATEDIFF(day,TO_DATE(st.Created_Date),TO_DATE(fs.Created_Date))>=8)


OR (DATEDIFF(day,TO_DATE(st.Created_Date),TO_DATE(mt.opacket_transactiontime))>=8)

)

AND  spc.spacket_disposition='A'    
AND TO_DATE(mt.OPacket_TransactionTime) >= TO_DATE('2021-07-11')
```

However I got 0 results.
So my guess is something wrong.
Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you debugged the query to check each condition one at a time? To isolate what works and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

`unix_timestamp()`  - Returns seconds in INT format.
Whereas `DATEDIFF` by default returns difference of dates in INT format.
So, i think, hive considers date + time difference but snowflake consider only date part and time part is ignored.
If you want to mimic hive logic in snowflake,  you should use below code -

```
select datediff(second, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, fs.Created_Date)/86400 >=8
```